# Obtaining normal of the mesh face using raycaster intersectObjects - Three.js

Tags: three.js, intersection, normals, raycasting

I tried to obtain the normal of the mesh face using these:

```
ray = new THREE.Raycaster(x, y); 
var intersection = ray.intersectObjects(objectsOptical, true);
var vector = intersection[0].face.normal;
```

Added intersection[0].point and intersection[0].face.normal (multiplied by constant) as one vertex and intersection[0].point as second vertex of a (gray) line. And I got this (red lines are rays and gray should be normals - but they are not):
[Illustrative image](http://www.foto-ondruskova.cz/Experiment/image.jpg)

Please help me to obtain NORMALS of the mesh FACE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The normals that you have plotted with red lines look like they might be correct taking into effect perspective projection.

The raycast test hits a single triangular face from your mesh. The normal you are referring to is the normal for the face object the ray hit, ie. from the original mesh.

In the [source code for THREE.Raycaster](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js#L253) the intersection calculations can be seen returning the face directly.

Elsewhere it is suggested that [Ray.intersectObjects() requires face centroids.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12788666/1176059) However I'm not sure about this since the source code doesn't refer to centroids.

Perhaps the normals in the original geometry weren't correct. Try this function first:

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
```